# How can I explain a few month gap in my career to focus on my studies?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I have a job interview soon and I'm worried because the current job I work at I left after a year then I rejoined them again after 8 months and now I've been there for a year so that's two years.

I left because it was my first year attending uni and I thought I need to be more committed to passing or else I wont be able to enroll to level 5. I came back to the company and that's when I was doing my level 5. Now that I finished uni I want to now find myself a permanent and better workplace.

Do I have to mention this to my interviewer? And if I do is this going to put them off?

Comment: Did you quit? or did you take a leave of absence? Did you have to reapply? or did you just give them a date you would be returning? Quitting is abrupt, a leave of absence is planned and negotiated.

Comment: I left the job and had the intention of coming back i didnt have to re apply or do an interview i sent the manager and email and asked for my position back because i felt ready to come back to work and my level 5 was based around my work environment which would have helped me in my uni work... (early years i studied) - in a nursery.. i didnt tell my manager i planned on coming back because i was unsure when i will come back but in the same year in march 2019 i left and came back december 2019 . No interview they took me stright away.

Answer (score 18):

> do i have to mention this to my interviewer?

No. You don't have to. You can just say you worked at that company for 2 years.

If you want to mention it (or they ask you) then you can say:

> I worked there for a year, then took an 8 month break to focus on my university work, and then returned for 1 year

That doesn't sound bad or go against you at all. If anything it shows you were responsible and made a good decision about your education and future.

Comment: It's also a plus that the company liked you enough to have you back

Comment: i have to admit its a good thing they didnt have to interview me or anything they took me back stright away but i am worried is this going to put them off me? and how can i clearly say it ? I joined in april 2018 then left in march 2019 then came back december 2019 i left for 8 months to dedicate and fully commit to my education at the time because it was important i give my 100% in passing my level 4 to enroll to level 5 - this job is for a nursery setting

Comment: I imagine a basic background check will reveal that you did not work there for the period you claimed, which will be a red flag that will remove you from consideration for the current job and possibly also blacklist you from future consideration.

Comment: i sent the wrong CV and the cv i sent was the one where it says april 2018 - current

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you did. Most companies will just accept it. If someone asks you for an explanation, you tell them that 8 months at university would improve what you can do and what benefit you in your career, and would benefit the next employer as well.

Comment: sorry i understood the first part but “ you tell them that 8 months at university would improve what you can do and what benefit you in your career, and would benefit the next employer as well.” can you be a little more clear with this please? — i joined in april 2018 and left march 2019 and re joined december 2019 i didnt need to do a interview or anything they took me stright away i took that 8 month gap to fully commit to my level 4 and ensure i pass so that i can get onto my level 5

Answer (score 0):

What is important in an interview, is your experience. Experience comes in many shapes or forms, even though it may not be immediately obvious to you how it's relevant to a particular job. Going back to school to learn more is generally seen as commendable, as you'll pick up **transferable skills** such as project and time management, meeting requirements set by others, and presentation and writing skills. Even if the topic you studied is not directly relevant for a job, the fact that you did study counts as experience. You can be proud of it, and should include it on your CV.